# NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserLoginStore<TUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a problem and I don't know how I fix it. I have created 1 login function with Facebook and Google. I got my account information but when it was time to call back at **`ExternalLoginCallback -> _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync`**, I got the error below. I don't know why. Looking forward to all the helpers. Thank you very much!

Here is my error:

```
NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserLoginStore<TUser>.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.GetLoginStore()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.FindByLoginAsync(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(string loginProvider, string providerKey, bool isPersistent, bool bypassTwoFactor)
ShopAuth.Core.Web.Client.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string remoteError) in AccountController.cs
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
```

Here is my code:

**UserStore.cs**

```cs
public class UserStore : IUserStore<AppUser>, IUserEmailStore<AppUser>, IUserPhoneNumberStore<AppUser>,
            IUserTwoFactorStore<AppUser>, IUserPasswordStore<AppUser>, IUserRoleStore<AppUser>, IUserLockoutStore<AppUser>
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public UserStore(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString");
    }

    // Some impl code here...
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```cs
public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, IEmailSender emailSender)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _configuration = configuration;
    _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString");
    _emailSender = emailSender;
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}

[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Logout));
    }
    else
    {
        // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
        var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel());
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error loading external login information during confirmation.");
        }
        var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

        var user = new AppUser
        {
            UserName = email,
            Email = email,
            FullName = model.FullName,
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View(nameof(ExternalLogin), model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IUserLoginStore<TUser>` in your `UserStore`. "Logins" are how external logins are stored, such as Facebook or Google login, not with a username or password. You will need to add that functionality so users can use external logins.